# Count com Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Tenho duas tabelas, Produtos e Itensvenda
Na tabela itensvenda tenho um FK de produtos.

Quero fazer a seguinte consulta usando hibernate criteria.

```
select count(itensvenda.prdcodigo), produtos.prddescricao  from itensvenda 
inner join produtos on itensvenda.prdcodigo = produtos .prdcodigo
group by itensvenda.prdcodigo, produtos.prddescricao
```

o código seguinte funciona?

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria();
c.createAlias("prdcodigo", "prdcodigo");
c.setProjection(Projections.count("prdcodigo.prdcodigo"));
c.setProjection(Projections.property("prdcodigo.prddescricao"));
c.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("prdcodigo.prdcodigo"));
c.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("prdcodigo.prddescricao"));
return c.list();
```

Comment: Guilherme, não consegue testar seu código? Se puder habilite o log de consultas em seu `DataSource` e veja se ficou igual. Na `Criteria` você não deve especificar o nome da tabela e seu atributos, e sim o nome da classe e seu campos (A implementação da JPA que esta usando é que irá traduzir de classe para tabela). E não está faltando a classe `Produtos` e o `inner join` com a `ItensVenda`?

Comment: O código que postei não funcionou.
Uma das minhas dúvidas é essa: como fazer o inner join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se na tabela ItensVenda você possui uma FK de Produtos (@ManyToOne pelo que eu entendi) você pode fazer o seguinte utilizando [DetachedCriteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html).

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ItensVenda.class);
detachedCriteria.createAlias("produtos", "produtos");
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("produtos.descricao"));
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("produtos.codigo"));
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("produtos.descricao"));
detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```

No caso tanto o alias quando as projections utilizam o nome das variáveis da clase "Produtos", lembrando que você vai obter como retorno uma lista de Strings.